# Spring Security: How to authorize user for a given URL when using multiple `http` elements?

Tags: java, security, spring-mvc, spring-security, authorization

I have a spring MVC web application built in a modular fashion. Each module that is added to the website may define its own security elements (using `http` namespace in xml) for user authorization, this is fine and working.

I now need to programmatically check if the current user has access to a given URL. I have searched and searched and found many references to the `WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator`, which would be great, except my application currently has 6 of these and I am not sure which one to use (it has 6 `<http:` elements). I have tried looping all 6 and performing the check on each one, but this returns strange results.

Example:

I can get all of the beans using the following:

```
private Collection<WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator> privEvals;
....
privEvals = (List<WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator>) applicationContext.getBeansOfType(WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator.class).values();
```

And loop check like this:

```
public void checkForUrl(String url) {
    for(WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator privEval:privEvals) {
        System.out.println(privEval.isAllowed(url, SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()));
    }
}
```

Example 1: The user is authorized for the URL, prints: 
false 
false 
true
true
true
true

Example 2: The same user is not authorized for the URL, prints:
false 
false
true
true
true
true

But if I try to browse to the URLs I get the correct `403` for the second url.

**Update**

If I use the other method of `WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator` which accepts context, I get the same result. I have tried many URLs with different `http` elements securing them, and the same boolean values are returned (in the same order).

If I use a different **user** with different roles assigned, I get the same problem where the results are always the same for different URLs (when the user is or isn't authorized to access them), except this time the following is printed:
false
true
true
true
false
true

**Update**

I have tried using the `<sec:authorize` tag with more strange results, it appears as though it is just using the first `WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator`.

Comment: Have you tried the other method of WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator that takes context path?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have updated my question in response, but in short yes I have, and no it doesn't work. I'm beginning to think I should just implement my own test that pings the URL and checks response, although I don't really want to do this as it will increase latency...

Comment: ok. The authorize JSP tag makes use of it and I have used it several times. Example: <sec:authorize url="/admin/" var="isAdministrator" />. The authorizeUsingUrlCheck method of AbstractAuthorizeTag is using the same code to check authorization.

Comment: This also doesn't work, It seems to return false to all users except one, user gets some trues. Therefore I assume it is just using one of the `WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator`

Comment: Yes. The AbstractAuthorizeTag uses the first one. See its getPrivilegeEvaluator() method.

Answer (score 1):

Old post but I get this problem and found no real answer.
My implementation for that is to select the good security realm using a specific Role to recognize the realm.

I get both WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator and FilterSecurityInterceptor

```
    ApplicationContext context = AppContext.getApplicationContext(); 
    Map<String, WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator> wipes = context.getBeansOfType(WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator.class);
    Map<String, FilterSecurityInterceptor> filters = context.getBeansOfType(FilterSecurityInterceptor.class);
```

I browse each and test the FilterSecurityInterceptor on a specific ROLE used for the realm :

```
    for (int i = 0; i < wipes.size(); i++) {
        privilegeEvaluator=(DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator) wipes.values().toArray()[i];
        FilterSecurityInterceptor filter = (FilterSecurityInterceptor) filters.values().toArray()[i];
        if (filter.getSecurityMetadataSource().getAllConfigAttributes().toString().contains("hasRole('SPECIFIC_ROLE')")) return privilegeEvaluator;
    }
```